# Cube fulfilled with Balls

Tags: contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Given a  cube $C$ with side length $N\cdot d$.

**Q**:

- Is there a method to fulfill the  $C$ with balls of diameter $d$.
- How to find the centers of these balls by a given coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are happy with cubic packing, the centers of the balls would be at the exact same locations as the centers of the N^3 small cubes, with side length d, that could be packed into C.